# Iterate through a List and remove miscellaneous members in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, collections, data-structures

In C++ using `std::list`, removing a member is a simple matter of erasing what an iterator is pointing to. (The erase statement returns the next valid member of the list.)

In .NET, what's the best way to iterate through a list and remove members that match a certain criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `List<T>`, one efficient way is to iterate through the list in reverse order, removing items as you go:

```
for(int i = myList.Count-1; i--; i>=0)
{
    if (ShouldBeRemoved(myList[i]))
    {
        myList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

If you instead have `IEnumerable<T>`, it gets more difficult as you can't alter a list while iterating.

Answer (score 9):

`List<T>` has the `RemoveAll` method, that takes a predicate and removes items: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx

`dinosaurs.RemoveAll(AddressOf EndsWithSaurus)`

```
Private Shared Function EndsWithSaurus(ByVal s As String) _
    As Boolean
    If (s.Length > 5) AndAlso _
        (s.Substring(s.Length - 6).ToLower() = "saurus") Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: @Soviut: `List<T>` is not a thread-safe class, nor is the `RemoveAll` method (it never takes a lock).

Comment: I like this a lot -- however, I'd like to have a list of all the junk that was RemoveAll'd so that I can process the rejects.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET you can't modify underlying collection during iteration with enumerator. So you have to options:

- iterate over your list with good ol' `for(;;)` loop;
- create a new list without items matching your criteria:

  var list1 = ...;
  var list2 = list1.Where(item => !criteria(item)).ToList();

(I've used C# for this sample but you should be able to convert it to VB).

Answer (score 1):

if you talking about foreach and using IEnumerator the answer is that you cannot remove anything from IEnumerable while iterating through it.
The only way is to store something (indexes of items) in another list and next delete them in loop

But here is the cookie: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidF2C8E1786AE76101911914CCA9286E25B398AED6.aspx?s=textbox

" Allows you to modify the underlying collection while in the middle of a foreach"

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)

    While lst.Count > 0
        lst.RemoveAt(0)
    End While
```

another solution